# Android: use developer.android.com offline?

Tags: android, offline, android-developer-api

I live in Iran and Google blocks Iranian internet users to access some of its utilities like [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com) website. Each time I'm going to use this website I have to set proxies that take the speed of my internet connection and make a lot of interrupts in it. Is there any possible ways to download [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com) website in order to use it offline?
Any tips or tricks will be appreciated.

Comment: Great question! Not sure if it's within the scope of this site though...

Comment: If the question is not related to this community, tell me and I'll delete the question for good.

Comment: Perhaps off-topic question, however, you can try website downloader softwares by google search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you download the Android SDK, you can include the documents, which have most of the information from developers.android.com. In addition, you might consider getting a copy of the offline Google kit, available from [this link](https://sites.google.com/site/gdgdevkitpilotreadme/).

Answer (score 1):

I personally use https://www.httrack.com/ to read the doc while I am in the train.

You can control the depth of crawling, the max size of file to download. It changes the links so they redirect to the local website

Comment: I have been using it for a long time also

Answer (score 0):

Download [Zeal](http://zealdocs.org/) its much recommended (from my side at least) :) It not only covers android but has options for other platforms too, happy coding brother.